# Django model: How to access "join table"?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64
```

So basically what I want to do here is access person/group/data_joined/invite_reason from a group object, how to write such a code? Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard reverse ForeignKey relationship:

```
my_group.membership_set.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can use `intertools`

```
import itertools

queryset = itertools.chain(Person.objects.filter(manytomany__isnull=False).order_by('name'),
                           Group.objects.filter(manytomany__isnull=False).order_by('name'),
                           Membership.objects.filter(manytomany__isnull=True).order_by('date_joined'))
```

Sultan